# How to create an NSButton that opens another window (Mac)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nswindow

Is it possible to set up an NSButton that leads to another (previously hidden) Mac OS window?

```
- (IBAction)loginb:(id)sender {
NSString *pass = [m_password stringValue];
NSString *name = [m_username stringValue];
if ([name isEqualToString:@"haseo98"] && [pass isEqualToString:@"passwordtest"]){
    [_loginwindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
}
else [_loginwindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
}
```

*Planning to put the code in place of the NSColor change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your window isn't in a window controller like Tom's answer suggests, you can also use `NSWindow`'s `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` method to display the window and have it to receive key events.

Comment: Thanks it worked :) is there code to hide the login window at the same time?

Comment: @haseo98 Then you should accept the answer as the correct one by clicking the gray checkmark next to it so that other people who stumble over this can find it easily :)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>It depends largely how you want to your login to behave. You could either use an instance of  `UINavigationController` and `pushViewController:animated:` which will also provide a navigation bar to use elsewhere in the app.</strike>

Or you could create an instance of the next view to be loaded, and use `[self addSubview:]`.

See:

> [How to change view on button click in iPhone without navigation controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290592/how-to-change-view-on-button-click-in-iphone-without-navigation-controller)
>
> [How to switch to next view when button is pressed iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372350/how-to-switch-to-next-view-when-button-is-pressed-iphone)
>
> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Edit: apologies, but you didn't specify that in the unedited question.

---

After a bit of poking around, it seems you can use the following;

```
if (_controller == nil)
{
   _controller = [[MyNewWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MyNewWindow"]; 
}

// Show the window.

[_controller showWindow:self];
```

Comment: Just to be clear the question was referring to a Mac os app, not ios :)